# Checking solution on discriminant of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-3})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

I am reviewing for an exam, and am trying to work out the discriminant of the number field $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-3})$, from the definition. Because $-3\equiv 1 (\text{mod}\; 4),$ we know the answer must be $-3$. However, when attempting to do it from the definition, I am getting mixed up. Here's my work. I'm using the fact that the discriminant of the number field with basis (as a $\mathbb{Z}$-module) $\{b_1,...,b_n\}$ and complex embeddings $\{\sigma_1,...,\sigma_n\}$ is $\left[\det(M_{ij})\right]^2,$ where $M_{ij}$ is the matrix whose $ij$ entry is $\sigma_i (b_j)$. Here, our basis is $\{1,\sqrt{-3}\},$ and our complex embeddings are $\{\sigma_1,\sigma_2\}$, where $\sigma_1$ is the identity, and $\sigma_2$ is the conjugate map. So, our matrix should be

$$\begin{pmatrix}
\sigma_1(1) & \sigma_1 (\sqrt{-3})\\
\sigma_2(1) & \sigma_2 (\sqrt{-3})
\end{pmatrix}$$

$$=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & \sqrt{-3}\\
1 & \sqrt{-3}
\end{pmatrix}$$

the determinant of this matrix is $-2\sqrt{-3}$, and the square of it is $-12$.

Where have I gone wrong? I should get $-3$ as the answer, not $-12$.

Comment: That's because the ring of integers is slightly larger than $\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt{-3}]$. And you forgot a minus sign in the second (invertible) matrix.

Comment: Ah, the ring of integers is $\mathbb{Z}(\frac{1}{2} + \frac{\sqrt{-3}}{2})$. So if I take the basis to be $\{\frac{1}{2}, \frac{\sqrt{-3}}{2}\}$, it will work out to $-3$?

Comment: $1/2$ is not an integer! Yes the ring of integers is $\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1}{2} + \frac{\sqrt{-3}}{2}]$

Comment: So then what should I choose as my basis? Should it be $\{1, \frac{1}{2}+\frac{-\sqrt{-3}}{2}\}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\{1,\sqrt{-3}\}$ is not a $\mathbb Z$-basis for $O_K$ since $x^2+x+1$ has root $w=\frac{-1+\sqrt{-3}}2$. This points to the correct basis $\{1,w\}$ and we get the matrix as
$$\begin{bmatrix}1&w\\1&\overline w=w^2\end{bmatrix}$$
with determinant $w^2-w=-2w-1=-\sqrt{-3}$ and square $-3$.

Comment: I'm probably not understanding some very simple reasoning. What does the polynomial $x^2+x+1$ and its root have to do with $\{1,\sqrt{-3}\}$ not being a basis for $\mathcal{O}_K$? How'd you get the basis you got?

Comment: @Luna145 This is an integral polynomial whose root is not in the $\{1,\sqrt{-3}\}$ basis. Clearly though $\sqrt{-3}$ is expressible as a linear combination of $1,w$, so $w$ replaces $\sqrt{-3}$ to get a strictly larger basis for _a subspace_ of $O_K$.

Comment: Excellent. Thanks so much.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel: Might it be better to say that the root of that polynomial is not in the *span over $\mathbb Z$* of the $\{1,-\sqrt{3}\}$ basis?

Comment: @LeeMosher I must have missed that...